# Image in ImageView not displaying behind Label?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am creating a launch screen for my app, I have a picture in an Imageview that I want as a backdrop for a Label containing the title of the app.

[Screenshot of the image in the background with Label in front of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67nNk.png)

I was able to shift the Label to the front of the launchscreen.storyboard, so that it is on top of the Imageview, by changing their position in the viewcontroller index.like so

When I load the sim for the app, the image doesn't appear, so it ends up looking like this:
[screenshot of launchscreen.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxn0b.png)

I haven't the foggiest ideas as to how to resolve this issue.
(Sidenote, I'm aware that nothing on the launchscreen.storyboard is aligned properly; I've removed all the constraints and I've been moving the moving things around in an effort to figure things out)

Is there something I need to drop into the Viewcontroller to make this happen?
I'm kind of at a loss..

Comment: Maybe you can do autoLayout  for  the imageView, select the iamgeView and click the `Add New Constraints`button, then make top-left-bottom-right = 0

Comment: oh snap! good thinking, ill try it

Comment: ..that didn't work. 
But I'll keep wracking my brain and googling!
:)

Answer (score 1):

Set the constraints to the image view to 0 for top-left-bottom-right. For the label, set the constraints to the top, center it to the page, and then set the size you want it to be. Sometimes when you change auto layout a lot within Xcode it gets buggy. You may want to delete all constraints and start fresh.

Comment: I've tried that, but I keep getting the following error:
"Leading constraint is missing, which may cause overlapping with other views."